# Paging in cakePHP not working with page

Tags: php, cakephp

I am using following query to get details.

```
$moods = $this->Mood->find('all', array('conditions'=>$conditions,
                    'joins' => array(
                            array(
                                'table' => 'users',
                                'alias' => 'user',
                                'type' =>  'INNER',
                                'conditions' => array(
                                    'user.id = Mood.userId',                                        
                                )
                            )
                    ),
                    'fields' => array('user.id','user.name','user.email','user.imagePath',
                        'Mood.id', 'Mood.moods', 'Mood.body', 'Mood.created', 'Mood.group', 'Mood.mediaName', 'Mood.mediaType', 'Mood.isPrivate'),

                    'order' => array('Mood.created DESC'),
                    'limit' => 10,
                    'page' => $offset
            ));
```

However the page is not workign no mater what offset i put the result is same , what is going on

Comment: How do you know it's not working? Where do you define`$offset`?

Comment: i am sending offset myself values 0 , 1 etc and they are returning same first 10 objects even with different values of 0 and 1

Comment: Pages aren't zero based, they start at `1`, so `0` and `1` are the same. That being said, you should do some debugging and come up with some details, start with inspecting the queries that are being issued. And please always mention the _exact_ CakePHP version that you are using and tag your question accordingly!

Comment: Why aren't you using [pagination](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/pagination.html)?

Answer (score 1):

hope this help

```
$this->Paginator->settings = array('conditions'=>$conditions,.........); 
$moods = $this->Paginator->paginate('Mood');
```

Comment: can u explain a little how this is going to work? where am i suppose to add offset or page number etc